# How to find out which device corresponds for /sys/bus/usb/devices/deviceN

Tags: linux, usb

I have a device connected to my Debian linux box, lsusb says:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0525:a4a7 Netchip Technology, Inc. Linux-USB Serial Gadget (CDC ACM mode)
```

In

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/
```

I have

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 0 Sep  7 14:27 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:27 1-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:27 2-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 13 08:32 2-3 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 13 08:32 2-3:2.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:2.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 13 08:32 2-3:2.1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:2.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:27 3-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:27 4-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:27 5-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb5/5-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:27 6-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb6/6-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:27 usb1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:27 usb2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:27 usb3 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:27 usb4 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:27 usb5 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  7 14:27 usb6 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb6
```

How to find out which device is this?

Answer (score 4):

I found / modify a script to get the `/sys` device based on `lsusb` output.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# usb2sys - find lsusb device in /sys file system
#

die()
{
    echo "$@"
    exit 1
}

[[ $# -lt 1 ]] && die "need vendor and product ids (from lsusb) as dddd:dddd"

vendor=${1%:*}
product=${1##*:}

sys=/sys/bus/usb/devices/
cd $sys

for d in *; do
    path=$sys$d
    if [ -f $path/idProduct ]; then
      prod=$( cat $path/idProduct )
      vend=$( cat $path/idVendor )

      if [ $prod = $product -a $vend = $vendor ]; then
        echo prod = $prod
        echo vend = $vend
        echo /sys device is $path
      fi
    fi
done
```

the idea is to get the string `1d6b:0002` and check agains which is the `idProduct:idVendor` couple and compare it to the existing `usb` in `/sys`

You can use the script like this

```
lsusb | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | xargs -L 1 ./usb2sys
```

The output would be something like

```
prod = 0002
vend = 1d6b
/sys device is /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2*/manufacturer` and progressively add numbers to the `2*` part.. like `2-3:*`, `2-3:2.*` until you can match the name, or use `idProduct` or `idVendor` instead of `manufacturer`.